# Construct a coherent subsheaf of a quasi-coherent sheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories

I am trying to prove the following statement

> Given a Noetherian scheme $X$ and a surjective morphism of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$: 
>   $$\mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{f} \mathcal{G} \to 0$$
>   where $\mathcal{G}$ is coherent, we can find a subsheaf $\mathcal{F'}$ of $\mathcal{F}$, which is coherent, such that the induced morphism
>   $$\mathcal{F'}\rightarrow \mathcal{G} \to 0$$
>   is also surjective.

---

My thought:

The algebraic version of this is obvious, that is, given a Noetherian ring $A$ and an epimorphism of $A$-modules $$M\to N\to 0$$
where $N$ is finitely generated, we can find a *finitely generated* submodule $M'$ such that the induced map $M'\to N$ is surjective.

So it is natural to restrict the morphism of sheaves on an affine open subset (we can find a finite affine open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$), 
$$\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}\cong \widetilde{M_i}, \ \ \ \ \mathcal{G}|_{U_i}\cong \widetilde{N_i}$$
for some $A_i$-modules $M_i$ and $N_i$, where $U_i=\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$.

Then for the map $M_i\to N_i$, we can find the finitely generated submodule $M_i'$. Thus, the coherent sheaf $\widetilde{M_i'}$ is the desired subsheaf, but unfortunately, only on $U_i$.

I am stuck at the point how to glue these subsheaves on $U_i$ together to get a coherent sheaf on $X$.

Any answer and hints are welcome!

---

I am not sure if the statement is true, but it is a promising "lemma" to show the derived category of the complexes of coherent sheaves is equivalent to the derived category of the complex of quasi-coherent sheaves with coherent cohomology, that is,
$$D^b(\mathrm{Coh}(X))\simeq D^b_{\mathrm{Coh}(X)}(\mathrm{QCoh}(X)).$$

---

Update:

This is true (see Lemma 3.6 on Huybrechts' *Fourier-Mukai Transforms in Algebraic Geometry*) and his proof is clear.

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing any conditions? It seems to me that if you take the identity map of any non-finitely-generated module you will have a counterexample.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, you are right. I forgot the condition that the target has to be finitely generated. I edited my question.